# ViewWillDisappear - UIAlertview

Tags: ios, uialertview

I have a `UITableviewController` with textfields in it. The textfields contain mandatory fields.

If the user leaves the screen without entering all the fields I want to alert the user with the alertview. I am doing this in the `viewwilldisappear` method. The alert pops but the view disappears. I dont want the view to navigate. Can this be done.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: why you do not check at button pressed event or some thing like that where user left your screen

Answer (score 0):

You might want to reconsider your workflow. Allowing the user to back out (and not proceed) will probably be a better plan.